# Vectorized rolling spread/split/subset

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` and I'd like to split it in sequential subsets with `cbind`. For example, with the following `data.frame`, I would like all sequences of 5 data points. The end result will be 3 columns (see below).

```
x <- data.frame(c(1,7,2,5,3,6,4))
```

Here's how I would do it with a loop, but I'd like something **vectorized**.

```
res <- NULL
for (i in 1:3){
  res_temp <- x[i:(i+4),]
  res <- cbind(res,res_temp)
}
res
     res_temp res_temp res_temp
[1,]        1        7        2
[2,]        7        2        5
[3,]        2        5        3
[4,]        5        3        6
[5,]        3        6        4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some solutions.  They all use the value of `k` in the first line:

```
k <- nrow(x) - 5 + 1

# 1 - embed
embed(x[[1]], k)[, k:1]

# 2 - sapply
t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(x) - k + 1), function(i) x[i + 1:k-1, 1]))

# 3 - rollapplyr
library(zoo)
rollapplyr(x[[1]], k, c)

# 4 - lag.zoo
library(zoo)
na.omit(lag(zoo(x[[1]]), 1:k-1))[]
```

Comment: This looks interesting, However, I do not know know how many columns I need. I guess this would work: `embed(x[[1]], nrow(x)-5+1)[, (nrow(x)-5+1):1]`

Comment: Yes, that would work.  Have updated answer to calculate k.

Answer (score 1):

I gather this should do:

```
> # input
> length_n <- 5
> x <- c(1,7,2,5,3,6,4)
> 
> # make table
> length_x <- length(x)
> n_new_cols <- length_x - length_n + 1
> final_n_elemnts <- n_new_cols * length_n
> 
> idx <- 0:(final_n_elemnts - 1)
> idx <- (idx %/% length_n) + (idx %% length_n) + 1
> out <- matrix(x[idx], ncol = n_new_cols)
> out
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    7    2
[2,]    7    2    5
[3,]    2    5    3
[4,]    5    3    6
[5,]    3    6    4
```

If `x` is not `vector` to start with then do `x <- df[[the_index_you_want]]`.